# How to create facebook style news feed (wall post) by using ASP.NET with jQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax, json

I am developing a web application by using asp.net 3.5 and sql server 2008R2. I have to create a page as like as facebook News Feed (wall post). I need post Status and reply comments. I know it will be done by jQuery but I am not expart of Query. Anyone help me with sample code or demo project?

Thanks
Nahid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a sample code for whole project doesn't seem to be the way things work on SO.

However for some things in which you should look is:

- Design Idea

  - Look at some of the web apps which already provide such feature like Hootsuit, Facebook, Sesmic, etc
- API (If using data from other websites)

  - [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)
- Data Handeling

  - Consider looking at Json.
  - Try out some hands on AJAX possibly from [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
  - Json Handling in (.Net) C#  with [Json.Net](http://jquery.com/) or [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)
  - [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) (If data querying from facebook)
- Authentication & Authorization

  - [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3fc21xw.aspx)
  - [ASP.Net Memberships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx)

And could be many more depending on how you specifically implement such feature in your website.

And don't forget using development tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/), will be very helpful when you debug your code.